# Looping through a large dataframe and perform sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a large file(~5GB) which I have loaded into a dataframe. Now I have to get a value(fid) from each row and fetch the corresponding row in the same dataframe.

```
var references = df.sqlContext.sql("Select authors,references,id from publications")
references.collect().foreach(ref => ref.getSeq[String](1).foreach(id => {
      val authors = ref.getSeq[String](0)
      val a = df.sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT authors from publications  WHERE id='$id'")

      }
))
```

I have tried the above code I get an out of memory exception because of the collect action. I tried increasing the memory and all but still no success.

Comment: can you share the schema of references dataftame by doing `df.printSchema()`? and can you share the reason for creating `val a`? we can suggest much better solutions I guess.

Comment: |-- authors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- references: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)  
@RameshMaharjan this is the schema for df 
Also "a" is being used for another calculation i need to do.

Comment: you didn't answer my second question.

Comment: the problem is like references is an array of id's and i need to loop through the references get the authors from the id's.

Comment: so it means that you are trying to filter out the rows when id column matches with any of the ids in references column and select the authors column. is that correct?

Comment: I'm a bit confused what your final output is meant to be, but I suspect the piece you're missing is the `explode` function in `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`. (In case that sparks a brainwave.)

Comment: yes. That is what i am trying to do. Final output is like the authors in a row are being referenced by the authors present in reference id's.

Comment: @Baam25, thanks for the clarification :) I have answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your requirement says that you are trying *select* `authors` column if `id` column's *value* matches any of the *ids* present in `references` array column.

You can acheive your requirement by defining a `udf` function

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def containsUdf = udf((ref: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String], id:String) => ref.contains(id))

df.select("authors").where(containsUdf(col("references"), col("id")))
```

The `udf` function is checking if the `references` columns *array* contains *value* of `id` column. It will return *true if the condition matches* *else will return false*.

**All the other inbuilt functions perform column wise, but `udf` function perform its operation row by row**.

The `udf` function is called in `where` function which *filters rows* when the `udf` function returns true.

It would be more clear if you use `filter` instead of `where` as

```
df.filter(containsUdf(col("references"), col("id"))).select("authors")
```

**Updated**

Above solution is for checking conditions within each row. But if your condition is to check on different rows then you should do the following. I have commented for clarification of the steps done

```
val tempId = df.select("id")  //creating temp table of id for inner join later on

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.select(col("authors"), explode(col("references")).as("id"))  // selecting authors and exploding references column so that each element of array in reference column is exploded to each row
  .join(tempId, Seq("id"))   // inner join the exploded dataframe with the temp table created above, this will filter out not matching id rows
  .select("authors")         // selecting only  the authors column
  .distinct()                // optional step for removing duplicate rows if any
```

Comment: Could you please explain what the function is doing

Comment: Actually my requirement was like the references array contains id's which are pointing to different row in the dataframe and not the same row. So I need to get the id's and search the dataframe for those rows and get those authors.

Comment: so it means that if row one id column is contained in row two references column. then you would want row two column only right?

Comment: let me explain with an example:
1st record -> "a" [2,3] 1
2nd record-> "b" [1] 2
so the result would be "b" for the  1st record and "a" for the 2nd record
because 2 in the array is the id for 2nd row and 1 in the 2nd record is id of 1st row.
Sorry for the long explanation but hope it cleared the question

Comment: what if you have 1st record -> "a" [2,3] 2 2nd record-> "b" [1] 2 ? or even more confusing 1st record -> "a" [2,3] 2 2nd record-> "b" [1, 2] 2 ?

Comment: the 3rd column is "id" which is unique. It cant be same for two rows

Comment: ok then lets make it 1st record -> "a" [1,2,3] 1 2nd record-> "b" [1] 2 ? or even more confusing 1st record -> "a" [1,2,3] 1 2nd record-> "b" [1, 2] 2 ?

Comment: the array contains id other rows. it cant contain id of itself.

Comment: I have updated the answer :) please check the last part. I have used comments for explanation :)